# Retrieving the subscription ID using the expand option in the \Stripe\Customer::retrieve

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to retrieve the subscription ID using just the Customer ID I have collected. I have tried the following in php:

```
// Retreive just a customer 
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve(
        $customer->id,
        ['expand' => ['subscriptions']]
    );
    $sub_data = $customer->subscriptions->data;
    var_dump($sub_data);
```

However, when I do, I receive "**Notice**: Trying to get property 'data' of non-object"

I expected that I would be able to dump all of the subscription data so I could then attempt to get the first subscription ID found.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure the customer provided has subscriptions?  You might want to try a `var_dump` of `$customer`.  The error message suggests there isn't anything in the `subscriptions` property.
2. Alternatively you can pass the Customer ID to the [List Subscriptions API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-customer) to just get the Subscriptions, if they exist.

Comment: Yes, I verified the subscription is correct with a var_dump. I did go with option 2 you recommended. This does work but thought I could save some code by using the expand option.